# Printing the final value of the iteration of a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having difficulties printing the final value of the array in order to increase the speed of the process. All variables are global. c is a 20 bit array. In the for loop, functiona(k) is called where certain formulas are applied to the values of k.

The Goal: I want to print only the value of the C array as shown in my code when k = 2^20-1. I have tried using an if statement but this does not work. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

```
int main(void)
{
    for(k=0;k<=2^20-1;k++)
    {
        functiona(k);
        //printf("\n");
        if(k == 2^20-1)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
            c[19], c[18],c[17],c[16],c[15],c[14],c[13],
            c[12],c[11],c[10],c[9],c[8],c[7],c[6],
            c[5],c[4],c[3],c[2],c[1],c[0]);)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `2^20` will give you a xored `20` and `2`. In C `^` is a XOR operator

Comment: Use `math.h`'s `pow( base, exponent )` function

Comment: @Isaiah There is a better way of calculating powers of 2 in C (bit shifting)..

Comment: why do you want to test it? just put it outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using xor operator in the if and for condition when you meant to use exponents.

Use math.h's `pow` function instead:

```
if ((pow(2, 20) - 1) == k)
```

Since this is power of two, you can also use bit shifting

```
if (((2 << 19) - 1) == k)
```

As someone pointed out in the comments, you could also write the above as this:

```
if (((1 << 20) - 1) == k)
```

**Remember -- Don't forget to change your for loop's condition too!**

Comment: Or, more idiomatically, `1 << 20`.

Comment: Yes, `1 << 20` replaces `2 << 19`.

Answer (score 0):

in you're code, while calling `functiona(k);`, you're passing `k` by value. Any changes made to the paramter by `functiona()` will not be reflected to `k`.

BTW, it's worthy to mention, `^` is `XOR` operator. Don't mistake that for exponent.

Also, I wonder, if you take a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table, you'll understand, the way `k<=2^20-1` or `k == 2^20-1` get executed in something completely different way from what you may think.

Maybe what you need here is the `pow()` function, as others already suggested.

That said, it looks like another `for` loop for `printf()` may help you very much.

Comment: k's a global var which means pass-by-reference sematics always

Comment: If that is the case, why to pass as argument?

Comment: He's a beginner... actually, he shouldn't pass an argument -- if he used Wextra, that should trigger a warning for overshadowng variables

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you append the values you want as you loop, then print whatever's in your variable at the end of the loop.

I made the loop go from max to 0, but you could also do

```
str = functiona(k) + str + " ";
```

if you wanted, i just find it easier to read if you're always appending to the end.

```
int main(void)
{
    for(k<=2^20-1;k=0;k--)
    {

        strcat (str, strcat(functiona(k), " "));
    }
    printf(str)
}
```

Edit: Whoops, I read this as Java haha. Edit'd strconcat.

Comment: It's good that you noticed that the print statement could be executed once after the loop, but `str += "stuff"` doesn't work in C. (I think the OP just wants to print the `c` array values calculated in ´functiona`, but that's a guess.)

Comment: Well, `str = ""` is still not correct. Neither is the `+` in `functiona(k) + " "`. Best skip the string stuff, I don't think it's needed here. (`functiona(k)` populates the golbal `c` array, which should be printed after the loop.)